# IIS - Post - Erro 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I configured my site in IIS as the image bellow:

[image]

"CTA_Ext" is a front-end project and "api" is a WebApi (c#) project

api project works as a "middleware" tha receives all resquest (by post) and redirect to another internal API's.

When i publish it with this configuration, I always get 405 error: Method Not Allowed

In my web.config i alread remove webdav module:

```
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="*" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

Does anybody knows what i can do to solve this problem?

Comment: According to your description, you say the api project is  a "middleware" tha receives all resquest (by post) and redirect to another internal APIs. Could you please tell me which throw the 405 error? Form the client side call middlewaer api or from the middlewaer api call the internal api?

Comment: @BrandoZhang, the error occurres when the call is from the cliente side to middlewaer api.

Comment: Could you please tell me where you put this web.config setting? Inside the API  or the CTA_Ext?

Comment: I tried to put this setting in both.

Comment: I suggest you could try to remve the web dev and test again, I couldn't understand why you remove it and re-add it again.

Comment: @BrandoZhang, i tried just remove webDav but without success

Comment: I suggest you could try to use Fail Request tracing to check which module return the method not allowed issue. More details about how to use FRT, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).